# TFS 2008 Build Release Note Like Report

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I would like to get some visibility of what changes have gone into our TFS build. Is there some way of finding out all of the resolved work items that have gone into the last X number of builds up to a certain date?

Could this be done by creating some kind of TFS report or query. If so, has this been done before?

[UPDATE]

I have discovered how to find all work items related to a single build. You can set up a work item query by specifying the Integration Build as follows:

```
TeamProject = @Project
State = Resolved
Integration Build = MyBuild_200912_02.01
```

However this is useless to me as we carry out builds every hour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's not easy.  You'll have to write a decent amount of code to crawl the TFS object model.  Reply if you really want to pursue this route.

While the results aren't as precise, it's much easier to make a query along the lines of:

```
Team Project = @Project
Resolved Date >= 12/2/2009
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the work item queries and it turns out that it is quite simple to do. Simply use the work item query below and you will get all resolved work items in your build up to a certain date.

```
Team Project = @Project
Integration Build Contains [Build Name]
State = Resolved
Resolved Date >= @Today - 365
```